Can I play on a game like krunker multiplayer with a friend without root on my mobile but like a developer? With like no root but developer?
The question is the title its.. This title you make, how do I find I'm drives to play with a friend as the find that can play with me on mobile.. With like not root but like a developer? In krunker preferably ..
The type of stuff that I was trying not really anything just seeing what files could do and learning c++ but knowing that's for developing it maybe thats the app section of not it probably could work.. Because itd be good using a file like csv on mine and next to me wanting to play.. Cool. Please help .

System usability scale , sus... I found out.. I'm going to with tryin  that..
